# Future Not Completed But Looks Like it Has

Tags: scala

I am a Scala newbie trying to understand Futures. I typed in the following in the REPL:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> val m = Future(println("Message"))
Message
m: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> Future(println("Another Message"))
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)
Another Message
```

In the first case I am assigning a Future computation to a variable `m`. I haven't called `m` yet but the Future actually produces the "Message" string output. But I also get a `Future(<not completed>)` message. What is going on here? Has the future completed or not? The string output tells me it has. Can somebody clear this up for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Future will start executing as soon as it is created (Depending on the ExecutionContext implementation and assuming resources are available for it to run.)

The fact that you see your message printed to the console indicates your Futures have completed.

Try the following and see what happens:

```
Future{
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println("Message")
}
```

Comment: That's a bit weird it starts executing after creation when I didn't even call it. I would have expected it to start executing when I call `m` in my example above.

Comment: This link explains what is going on behind the scenes: https://www.beyondthelines.net/computing/scala-future-and-execution-context/

Comment: @Mojo `m` isn't `lazy` or a `def`. It will get computed when it is defined. If you want it to wait until it's called before it computes, pop it in a function or make the val lazy.

Comment: So basically if I had a future in my program which was assigned to a variable, when the thread of execution passes through that part of the program, the future will start executing??

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I just saw your message before I posted my new comment. OK, so default behaviour is to let a future value rip straightway even if it is assigned to variable unless I make it lazy.

Comment: The simple answer is yes but in reality it depends on your ExecutionContext implementation and how many Futures have been created. If you create thousands of Futures then they may get queued.

Comment: @Mojo yeah it's the same with any `val`s. if they aren't lazy (or aren't defined as `def m = ....`), they will be read into memory as and when they are defined. Making a val `lazy` basically tells the compiler to not worry about working out its value until it is used later on - it might as well be a comment or new line as far as the compiler is concerned at that point (once it has found out that the val is lazy).

Comment: Although as @TerryDactyl points out, different ExecutionContexts run differently so this isn't a universal rule. As far as `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is concerned though, you can assume it to be correct.

Comment: @Mojo If you don't like the eager execution behavior of `Future` you could check out the various `IO` monads out there, such as `cats.effect.IO`, which give you a lot more control. Admittedly, however, there is an increase in complexity involved, especially if you're not used to the functional paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

It is completed, what you see `Future(<not completed>)` is just the `toString() from the Future.

try:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f = scala.concurrent.Future{
  println("Message")
}

println(f.toString())
```

Future execute always eagerly.